# Search an element in a list and remove it in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
mylist = [["i", "love", "to", "eat", "tim tam"], ["tim tam", "is", "my", "favourite", 
"chocolate", "and", "i", "eat", "it", "everyday"]]
```

I also have a list namely `stops` as below.

```
stops = ["and", "the", "up" "to", "is", "i", "it"]
```

Now, I want to search through `mylist` and remove the aforementioned `stops` from it. Hence, my final `mylist` will look as below.

```
mylist = [["love", "eat", "tim tam"], ["tim tam", "my", "favourite", "chocolate", "eat", "everyday"]]
```

My current code is as follows.

```
for k in mylist:
    for item in k:
        if k in stops:
            pop(k)
```

It gives me `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Please help me.

Comment: Did you mean `if item in stops:`?

Comment: @omijn Oh, stupid me :D I didn't notice it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new list that contains the result:

```
[[i for i in s if i not in stops] for s in mylist]
```

A more efficient way to do this is to create a set out of `stops`, making the membership test faster:

```
stops_set = set(stops)
[[i for i in s if i not in stops_set] for s in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Brute force Solution:

```
mylist = [["i", "love", "to", "eat", "tim tam"], ["tim tam", "is", "my", "favourite", 
"chocolate", "and", "i", "eat", "it", "everyday"]]

stops = ["and", "the", "up","to", "is", "i", "it"]

for currlist in mylist:
    for i in stops:
        if i in currlist:
            currlist.remove(i)

print(mylist)
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: The answer has already been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068199/search-an-element-in-a-list-and-remove-it-in-python?noredirect=1#comment81084357_47068199). Does your answer add anything substantial over it besides a copy-paste of the code?

Comment: it should be; `for currlist in mylist:
    for i in currlist:
        if i in stops:` right? :)

Comment: @Volka even that will work fine

Comment: @COLDSPEED check the link which you have mentioned, it is link of this question itself. please verify